# I'm unable to connect to the linux using the ssh private key

Tags: ssh, users, openssh, sshd

I have created a new user account and have copied ssh public key from an existing user account to the new user account. I have copied this public key to /home/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys

When I try to connect from the host machine using the ssh private key from this new user account, I get prompted to enter the password.

```
$ ssh -i my-remote-key remote_user@remote_machine
```

I'm not sure why exactly I need to enter the password to connect to the Linux machine. When I try to connect to the same Linux machine from the same host using a different user account I don't get prompted to enter the password.

I have checked the permissions of the ssh public key it has been set to 600.

Also, I would like to know if the ssh keys are specific to a user account.

Comment: Is you public key included in the remote_user ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file?

Comment: Have you also checked the remote user's `~/.ssh/config` file permissions (if that file exists)? If you are asking whether the reason for the existing key not working with a new user account could be that the key is already used by an older user account, then no, that should not be an issue. The SSH server may be configured to only allow specific users to use public key authentication. Do you have access to the server's `sshd_config`?